# Why are there 2 parentheses after Function

Tags: javascript, function, return, brackets, create-function

```
function sample(banana)
       {return new Function('return ' + banana)() }
```

Why are there  2 parentheses after Function?

Is the first  parenthese the argument for the newly created function.?
What does the second  parentheses do?

Comment: `()` invokes a function

Comment: They execute the function.

Comment: the better question is: why do you create a new function and call this function immediately?

Comment: @NinaScholz seems like an example. But yes, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a function with parentheses `()`

```js
x = new Function('return 0');
console.log(x());


//...is same as

console.log(new Function('return 0')())
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to think about it in separate steps:

```
function sample(banana) {

  // Create a new function that can be invoked later
  var myNewFunc = new Function('return ' + banana)

  // Invoke the function
  var result = myNewFunc()

  return result

}
```

Now start removing the extra steps.

First return the result of the invoked function without storing in a separate variable:

```
function sample(banana) {

  // Create a new function that can be invoked later
  var myNewFunc = new Function('return ' + banana)

  // Invoke the function and return the result
  return myNewFunc()

}
```

Now you can remove the variable that stores the function:

```
function sample(banana) {

  // Create a new function and invoke it immediately
  return new Function('return ' + banana)()

}
```